# Angular WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4200/ng-cli-ws' failed

Tags: angular, google-chrome, websocket

I am working on an Angular project, but live reload is very unreliable. After running `ng serve`, live reload works normally for a minute or so, but then it stops working and I get these errors in Chrome `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4200/ng-cli-ws' failed:`  and a [webpack-dev-derver] error object that looks like this

```
Event {
isTrusted: true,
bubbles: false,
cancelBubble: false,
cancelable: false,
composed: false,
currentTarget: WebSocket {__zone_symbol__errorfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__openfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYerror: ƒ, __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYopen: ƒ, __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYclose: ƒ, …},
defaultPrevented: false,
eventPhase: 0,
returnValue: true,
srcElement: WebSocket {__zone_symbol__errorfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__openfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYerror: ƒ, __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYopen: ƒ, __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYclose: ƒ, …},
target: WebSocket {__zone_symbol__errorfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__openfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYerror: ƒ, __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYopen: ƒ, __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYclose: ƒ, …},
timeStamp: 50222.70000000298,
type: error",
[[Prototype]]: Event
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "wave-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "15.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "15.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "15.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

Refrehsing the page sends me to the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` screen. I have no idea what to do to solve the issue and it makes developing  in a local env very difficult when I cannot tell whether the changes made to the code did not work or if the live reload has broken again. Has anyone else come across this issue? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, was able to fix it by removing the `publicHost` from angular.json
[image: image description]

Answer (score 0):

The error "Angular WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4200/ng-cli-ws' failed" indicates a failed connection between your Angular application and the development server. Here's a breakdown of troubleshooting steps:

**1. Verify Development Server:**

Ensure it's running using ng serve. Check port and path match your configuration (usually in angular.json).

**2. Browser Compatibility:**

Modern Chrome requires secure WebSockets (wss://) on localhost.
Consider temporarily disabling Chrome's security (not recommended for production).

**3. Firewall or Proxy:**

Verify your firewall allows connections to port 4200.
Configure your development server for proper proxy handling if necessary.

**4. Code-Related Issues:**

Review your code for conflicts affecting WebSocket connections.
Ensure Angular and Angular CLI versions are compatible.

***5. Additional Tips:***

Clear browser cache and hard reload.
Restart development server.
Avoid Deleting Unnecessary Configuration:

Don't delete **stylePreprocessorOptions** from **angular.json** unless you're using a custom preprocessor setup.